# What are the disadvantages of adding subview to UIWindow?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiwindow

I am new to ios developement, actually i want to add UICollectionView to top of everything. So, for that i am adding this to UIWindow, what basically i want to know that is there any disadvantage to adding UICollectionView to UIWindow. If yes then, Is there any way of adding any object to the top of everything?
Thanks.

Comment: why you want it to add it over UIWindow, you can Have your collectionView inside your UIViewController and put at the top of your views Hierarchy.

Comment: I want that collection view throughout my app.

Comment: There is no disadvantage until you need device rotation.

Comment: Not able to understand your point. If collection is view going to be on top of everything else then how user will able to interact with other functionalities? If there is no other functionality involved, then why not to put collectionview on viewcontroller itself?

Comment: You can alternatively use `bringSubviewToFront` method everytime you want the collectionview to be on top of everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the idea of the UIWindow is to hold 1 rootViewController and not play with that too much, only use it in cases you need to get the main view.

The right way to do so is to have 1 main NavigationController and to override it with what-ever kind of top view you want (i.e. side menu, various overlays, etc..), this way its always accessible from the subControllers and you have a complete handling of that inside a UIViewController with all of the relevant delegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

Other than that it is generally considered bad practice and the `UIKit` should be providing you with an alternative method to avoid this kind of usage, the biggest problem I can think of is that views added directly to the `UIWindow` do not respond to device orientation change (rotation) events and will not rotate with the rest of the UI.

Comment: Keyboard has its own window. Modals used to also have their own window.